# how do I get mouse position while pressing a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm trying to get the mouse position while pressing a button, but instead of getting the position of the mouse on Tkinter root, it gives me the position of the mouse on the button. For example, if the button is placed on 200, 200, and I press the top left of the button, it prints 0, 0 instead of 200, 200.

```py
import Tkinter as tk

def leftclick(event):
    print("left")
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))

root = tk.Tk()
add_user = tk.Button(root, height=63, width=195 ,text="sign up a user")
add_user.place(x= 20, y = 30)
root.bind("<Button-1>", leftclick)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i added a minimal code to show how I get the mouse's position

Comment: missing `(event)` in definition.

Comment: thanks, ofcourse I have it coded. forgot to type it here.

Comment: the error has to be somewhere else. When i use `leftclick` exactly like you posted it, just adding `print(x, y)`at the end, and creatig a simple window with a button, it prints the window coordinates, not the button coordinates.

Comment: Try using `x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()` and similar for y. Tkinter can be a bit fiddly with coordinates, this seems to be the most robust to me. This takes the absolute location of the pointer on the screen and subtracts the absolute location of the top-left corner of root window on the screen.

Comment: thank you so much!!!! @fhdrsdg

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `winfo_pointerx` and `winfo_pointery` methods of a widget to get each individual coordinate, or you can call `winfo_pointerxy` to get them both:

```
def leftclick(event):
    x, y = event.widget.winfo_pointerxy()
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
```